# Selenium WebDriver - Unable to click on a button inside a frame in IE 9

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-9

I am working with a button inside a frame. I changed the control to the frame by giving `driver.switchTo().frame(3)` and was successful in clicking on the Add New Client button when running it in Mozilla Firefox 35.0. The same code does not work in IE 9. Could someone tell me what could be the reason and help me with this?

Here is the `HTML` snippet.

```
<a id="BtnAddNew" class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" role="button" style="right: auto; left: 389px; margin: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <span id="BtnAddNew-btnWrap" class="x-btn-wrap" unselectable="on">
     <span id="BtnAddNew-btnEl" class="x-btn-button">
     <span id="BtnAddNew-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center" unselectable="on">Add New Client</span>
     <span id="BtnAddNew-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon-el " style="" unselectable="on" role="img"></span>
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: I get the following stack message - TestNG
`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame found (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 80 milliseconds`

Please let me know in case of additional information.

Comment: Please post your selenium code and check if the `frame` index is correct in IE

Comment: Selenium Code:

`driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
 
driver.switchTo().frame(3);


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'BtnAddNew-btnIconEl')]")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

driver is not switching to the exact frame id.Assuming that there are mupltiple windows which causing this issue.

Comment: @ Srinivasulu Reddy, When WebDriver is running I have only one window.  The page is segregated into three frames 1. A left Panel where all the links are available, 2. the Menu bar and 3. the main container. The Add New Client button in present in the main container. The same selenium code works fine in FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: It is an issue with IE driver server which is being used. Please try with new version of IE driver (IEDriverServer_2.45.0)  . It will solve the issue for sure